# How to use java libraries in ios project?(codenameone)

Tags: xamarin, codenameone, ikvm

I need to connect native java libraries for use in the ios environment. In particular, it is necessary to use ready-made support for crypto libraries.

I tried using ikvm(.net core xamarin) for ios. but there is no support for mono-touch.

Answer (score 0):

See [this answer](https://help.codenameone.com/en-us/article/can-i-use-any-jar-1uav2ka/) from the knowledge base.

> You can't use an arbitrary JAR "as is". Please also check the maven dependency discussion in [this post](https://www.codenameone.com/blog/moving-to-maven.html).
>
> You can wrap libraries as [cn1libs](https://www.codenameone.com/cn1libs.html) but a library might use arbitrary Java code which might be a problem, see [this](https://www.codenameone.com/blog/why-we-dont-support-the-full-java-api.html).